# Convert from flat XML file to hierarchical XML file using LINQ to XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Using C# and LINK to XML, this "flat" XML file that comes from a variable called "xVar"

```
   <vWorkflows>
      <vSection sectionTitle="Bars" sectionId="4">
        <vCategory catTitle="Between Visits" catRef="13">
          <type typeTitle="" typeRef="">
            <link linkNum="">
              <linkTitle>placeholder1</linkTitle>
              <linkSummary></linkSummary>
              <linkKeywords></linkKeywords>
              <pubDate>2012-05-01 00:00:00</pubDate>
              <lastUpdate>2012-05-18 00:00:00</lastUpdate>
            </link>
          </type>
        </vCategory>
      </vSection>
      <vSection sectionTitle="Pre-Visit" sectionId="1">
        <vCategory catTitle="Scheduling" catRef="4">
          <type typeTitle="" typeRef="">
            <link linkNum="">
              <linkTitle>placeholder2</linkTitle>
              <linkSummary></linkSummary>
              <linkKeywords></linkKeywords>
              <pubDate>2012-05-02 00:00:00</pubDate>
              <lastUpdate>2012-05-19 00:00:00</lastUpdate>
            </link>
          </type>
        </vCategory>
      </vSection>
      <vSection sectionTitle="Patient Visit" sectionId="2">
        <vCategory catTitle="Check-in" catRef="5">
          <type typeTitle="" typeRef="">
            <link linkNum="">
              <linkTitle>placeholder3</linkTitle>
              <linkSummary></linkSummary>
              <linkKeywords></linkKeywords>
              <pubDate>2012-05-03 00:00:00</pubDate>
              <lastUpdate>2012-05-20 00:00:00</lastUpdate>
            </link>
          </type>
        </vCategory>
      </vSection>
      <vSection sectionTitle="Patient Visit" sectionId="2">
        <vCategory catTitle="Check-in" catRef="5">
          <type typeTitle="" typeRef="">
            <link linkNum="">
              <linkTitle>placeholder4</linkTitle>
              <linkSummary></linkSummary>
              <linkKeywords></linkKeywords>
              <pubDate>2012-05-04 00:00:00</pubDate>
              <lastUpdate>2012-05-21 00:00:00</lastUpdate>
            </link>
          </type>
        </vCategory>
      </vSection>
      <vSection sectionTitle="Bars" sectionId="4">
        <vCategory catTitle="Registration" catRef="3">
          <type typeTitle="" typeRef="">
            <link linkNum="">
              <linkTitle>placeholder5</linkTitle>
              <linkSummary></linkSummary>
              <linkKeywords></linkKeywords>
              <pubDate>2012-05-05 00:00:00</pubDate>
              <lastUpdate>2012-05-22 00:00:00</lastUpdate>
            </link>
          </type>
        </vCategory>
      </vSection>
    </vWorkflows>
```

... needs to end up looking like

```
<workflows>
  <section sectionTitle="Bars" sectionId="4">
    <category catTitle="Between Visits" catRef="13">
      <type typeTitle="" typeRef="">
        <link linkNum="">
          <linkTitle>placeholder1</linkTitle>
          <linkSummary></linkSummary>
          <linkKeywords></linkKeywords>
          <pubDate>2012-05-01 00:00:00</pubDate>
          <lastUpdate>2012-05-18 00:00:00</lastUpdate>
        </link>
      </type>
    </category>
    <category catTitle="Registration" catRef="3">
      <type typeTitle="" typeRef="">
        <link linkNum="">
          <linkTitle>placeholder5</linkTitle>
          <linkSummary></linkSummary>
          <linkKeywords></linkKeywords>
          <pubDate>2012-05-05 00:00:00</pubDate>
          <lastUpdate>2012-05-22 00:00:00</lastUpdate>
        </link>
      </type>
    </category>
  </section>
  <section sectionTitle="Patient Visit" sectionId="2">
    <category catTitle="Check-in" catRef="5">
      <type typeTitle="" typeRef="">
        <link linkNum="">
          <linkTitle>placeholder3</linkTitle>
          <linkSummary></linkSummary>
          <linkKeywords></linkKeywords>
          <pubDate>2012-05-03 00:00:00</pubDate>
          <lastUpdate>2012-05-20 00:00:00</lastUpdate>
        </link>
      </type>
    </category>
    <category catTitle="Check-in" catRef="5">
      <type typeTitle="" typeRef="">
        <link linkNum="">
          <linkTitle>placeholder4</linkTitle>
          <linkSummary></linkSummary>
          <linkKeywords></linkKeywords>
          <pubDate>2012-05-04 00:00:00</pubDate>
          <lastUpdate>2012-05-21 00:00:00</lastUpdate>
        </link>
      </type>
    </category>
  </section>
  <section sectionTitle="Pre-Visit" sectionId="1">
    <category catTitle="Scheduling" catRef="4">
      <type typeTitle="" typeRef="">
        <link linkNum="">
          <linkTitle>placeholder2</linkTitle>
          <linkSummary></linkSummary>
          <linkKeywords></linkKeywords>
          <pubDate>2012-05-02 00:00:00</pubDate>
          <lastUpdate>2012-05-19 00:00:00</lastUpdate>
        </link>
      </type>
    </category>
  </section>
</workflows>
```

It sort of works with the following, but my brain gets fuzzy trying to get all the attributes in the first "group by" and how to add the other groupings that inevitably follow.

```
   XDocument xDoc = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
        new XComment("XML Source Data for Dial Flash"),
        new XElement("workflows",
            from sec in xVar.Elements("vSection")
            //group sec by (string)sec.Attribute("sectionTitle").Value,
            group sec by (string)sec.Attribute("sectionTitle").Value into gsec
            select new XElement("section", 
                new XAttribute("sectionTitle", gsec.Key)
            ) 
        )
    );
```

Is there a better way to do this? Bonus if the dates can be converted to MM/dd/yyyy in the process...

Comment: Is using XSLT out of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        var xVar = XElement.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

        var query = xVar.Elements("vSection").
            GroupBy(grp => (string)grp.Attribute("sectionTitle")).
            Select(grp => new XElement("section", grp.First().Attributes(),
                grp.Select(vsec => new XElement("category",
                    vsec.Element("vCategory").Attributes(),
                    vsec.Element("vCategory").Elements()))
                )
            )
        ;

        var xml = new XElement("workflows", query);
```

Comment: Awesome, and I was able to fix the date format when creating the source XML file.